# Ensure to close files in Ruby, with rescue and ensure

Tags: ruby, file

I have the following code:

```
begin
   @output_file = File.open("output.txt", "w")
   File.read(@input_file).each_line do |line|
   taxify_line(line)
end
rescue => e
   p "Smz went wrong..."
end
@output_file.write("Last line of output")
@output_file.close unless @output_file.nil?
```

What is the correct way of ensuring that regardless of I catch an exception, both files (@input_file and @output_file) are closed?

Answer (score 6):

`rescue` clause should be inside of begin..end block. And there's also, surprise, `ensure` clause that does exactly what you might think

```
begin
   @output_file = File.open("output.txt", "w")
   File.read(@input_file).each_line do |line|
     taxify_line(line)
   end
rescue => e
   p "Smz went wrong..."
ensure
  @output_file.write("Last line of output")
  @output_file.close unless @output_file.nil?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I don't want to write on the @output_file if something went wrong? So, avoid doing this: @output_file.write("Last line of output") -- Where should I place that line then?

Comment: In your main body (before rescue).

Comment: I read the following in Pragmatic programming ruby book; and have become somewhat confused. Can some one please clear this up:
#start_of_code
f = File.open("testfile")
  
begin
# .. process
rescue
# .. handle error
ensure
f.close
end
  
#end_of_code
"Beginners commonly make the mistake of putting the File.open inside the begin block. In
this case, that would be incorrect, because open can itself raise an exception. If that were to
happen, you wouldn’t want to run the code in the ensure block, because there’d be no file
to close."